# Homotopy is an equivalence relation on the set of all loops on X.

Tags: equivalence-relations

How can I prove "Homotopy is an equivalence relation on the set of all **loops** on $X$." using the definition of homotopy $rel$ for loops:

Let $f, g$ be two loops in $X$ based at $x$, i.e. $f(0) = f(1) = x = g(0) = g(1)$. We say that $f$ is homotopic to $g$ and write $f \sim{g}$  if  $f \sim{g}$ $rel_A$ where $A=\{0,1\} $, i.e if there exists a homotopy 
$$H : I \times I \rightarrow X, $$
such that
$$H(s,0) = f(s),H(s,1) = g(s), \forall s \in I,$$
and
$$H(0,t) = H(1,t) = x, \forall t \in I.$$

Comment: What are you exactly struggling with?

Answer (score 1):

I can prove it like in path. **But here I didn't use the relative homotopy for loops neither the fact that** $f(0)=f(1)=x$.

(i)  Reflexivity  ($f\sim f$). Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces and $f:X\longrightarrow Y$ be a loop. Define $F:X\times I\longrightarrow Y$ by $F(x,t)=f(x), \forall x\in X.$ Then $F$ is continuous and $F(x,0)=F(x,1)=f(x)$ for all $x\in X.$ So $f\sim f.$

(ii) Symmetry ($f\sim g\Rightarrow g\sim f$). Suppose that $f,g:X\longrightarrow Y$ are two loops and $f\sim g.$ Then there is a map $F: X\times I\longrightarrow Y$ such that $F(x,0)=f(x)$ and $F(x,1)=g(x)$ for every $x\in X.$ Define a mapping $G:X\times I \longrightarrow Y$ by $G(x,t)=F(x,1-t).$ Then $G$ is continuous,  $G(x,0)= F(x,1)=g(x)$ and $G(x,1)=F(x,0)=f(x)$, for every $x\in X.$  Therefore, $g\sim f.$

(iii) Transitivity ($f\sim g ,  g\sim h\Rightarrow f\sim h$). Suppose that $f,g,h:X\longrightarrow Y$ are three loops such that $f\sim g$ and $g\sim h.$  Then there is a map $F:X\times I\longrightarrow Y$ such that $F(x,0)=f(x)$ and $F(x,1)=g(x)$ for every $x\in X$ and another map $G:X\times I\longrightarrow Y$ such that $G(x,0)=g(x)$ and $G(x,1)=h(x)$, for every $x\in X.$ Define a mapping $H:X\times I\longrightarrow Y$ by
\begin{align*}
H(x,t) = \begin{cases}
F(x,2t)&,  0\leq t\leq\dfrac{1}{2}, \\
G(x,2t-1)&,  \dfrac{1}{2}\leq t\leq 1.
\end{cases} 
\end{align*}
It is clear that $F$ is continuous in $[0,\dfrac{1}{2}]$ and $G$ is continuous in $[\dfrac{1}{2},1].$ Hence, according to glueing lemma $H$ is continuous on $[0,1].$ Moreover, $H(x,0)= F(x,0)=f(x)$ and $H(x,1)=G(x,1)=h(x).$ Thus $f \underset{H}{\thicksim} h.$

Therefore homotopy is an equivalence relation.